# Is estimation partition functions without resorting to markov chain monte carlo still an open question?

Tags: partition-function, algorithms

I was told estimation of partition functions without resorting to MCMC was still an open question in physics about a year and a half ago.  An example is that say you have some physical model that obeys a Boltzmann distribution: $p(x) \sim \frac {e^{f(x)}}{Z(x)}$.  The objective is to calculate $Z(x)$, without resorting to some form of rejection sampling.  I don't think partition function estimation was this person's field so he may have not been fully informed, but he was a professor of physics.  I'm curious because [this paper](https://openreview.net/pdf?id=SylkYeHtwr) is one of many that have dealt with and may have solved this issue in machine learning if I'm understanding this right from a physics perspective (which I may not be).

In order to help me understand this question, it may be helpful to explain what issues there are with this method for estimating partition functions that are needed in physics if it still is an open question.  If it is not an open question, perhaps it may be interesting to point to the papers that have solved this if they were proposed recently.

PS That paper also owes a debt of gratitude for physicists for introducing Russian roulette estimator.

Comment: What do you mean "solved"? You can always look for faster, more precise algorithms..

Comment: by solved, I mean a solution that doesn't require rejection sampling or other methods with similar computational costs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to discuss my knowledge of sampling methods and their application to partition function estimation from a physical point of view. I am not a statistician, so I can't provide any meaningful input on the paper in your link: maybe some statisiticians could help with that?

For a reduced potential energy function $u(\vec{x})$ the configurational partition function over a configurational volume $V$ is (barring any proportionality constants):

$$Z_1 = \int_{V} e^{-u(\vec{x})} d\vec{x}$$

Now, as you have already seen, this is a $3N$-dimensional integral which can only be estimated by probabilistic methods (quadrature results in a combinatorial explosion). The problem with the exponential term is that an overwhelming number of sample points will have a negligible Boltzmann factor, while the terms that contribute the most (the low energy configurations) are extremely rare. Therefore, the variance of any integral estimate is going to be extremely high and not practically useful. That's why your best bet is to convert this into a sampling problem.

The way to do this is to start with a distribution whose partition function you know (usually a uniform distribution, in which case $Z_0=V^{N}$) and then use any method which can estimate ratios of normalisation constants and/or free energy differences $\Delta f_{01}$, since $\frac{Z_1}{Z_0} = e^{-\Delta f_{01}}$. There are many methods which can estimate free energy differences, but all of them rely on intermediate connecting distributions $Z_{\lambda},\lambda\in (0,1)$. However, in order to sample from these you need global sampling, which with regular sampling methods is extremely inefficient (the efficiency decreases exponentially with the kinetic barrier heights, i.e. roughly with system size).

Alternatively, you can recast the partition function as a one-dimensional integral:
$$Z_1 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-u}\Omega(u)du$$
for a density of states $\Omega(u)$:
$$\Omega(u) = \int_{V} \delta(u(\vec{x})-u) e^{-(u(\vec{x})-u)} d\vec{x}$$
which means that you "only" need to estimate the density of states and you are done! Of course, this is the difficult bit, but there is a method which claims to do that even for high-dimensional systems: nested sampling (NS). I am not going to go into detail, you can read about it if you are interested, but suffice it to say that this method results in [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.03404.pdf) impressive paper, where they calculate a whole phase diagram based on estimating the density of states.

Another method that provides the level of sampling needed to estimate the density of states is sequential Monte Carlo (SMC). In fact, statisticians much prefer SMC to NS and it has been [suggested](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.03924.pdf) that SMC is indeed a generalisation of NS. SMC is a path-integral-like method which also traverses intermediate distributions from the uniform distribution to the distribution of interest, but it uses a survival of the fittest mechanism, which only results in good trajectories through parameter space.

In all cases, estimating partition functions is still very difficult and the scaling is highly polynomial at best (but practically still likely exponential), so I would say this is probably still an open problem, but it is entirely conceivable that it is impossible to come up with an algorithm with a lower computational complexity than what we currently have - only time will tell.

Comment: I'm familiar with SMC for state-space modeling.  I guess my knowledge of physics is limited but do you need the sequential aspect because the space variables are also a function of time?

Comment: Sorry it wouldn't let me edit.  A second point.  SMC is usually pretty fast if you run it once.  The problem is most algorithms require running a particle filter 100s of thousands of times, in which case running time of a couple of seconds can be problematic.  What is the end objective?  Are we trying to estimate the parameters of u(x)?  Again I don't understand the physics at all, but coming into from a statistics point of view.

Comment: There are several completely different applications for SMC and one, as  you said, is parameter inference. However, you can also use SMC to sample from the posterior distribution (your known potential of choice) given a prior distribution (e.g. uniform distribution) and intermediate distributions, corresponding to softened potentials. In the process, you can also estimate the partition function ratio $\frac{Z_1}{Z_0}$, which is what we were after in the first place.

Comment: Concerning your first question, time is only relevant in that it provides refreshed samples - if you want to obtain a partition function, there's not much useful information from the "physically" generated time-evolution anyway, so you can use any sampling method. You can use e.g. leapfrog integration, but you could also use Markov chain Monte Carlo (which is indeed the method of choice in most statistical applications).

Comment: Based on your comments I am reasonably confident (70%) the use of variational inference to solve this problem will lead to speeds at least 10x faster than SMC/MCMC.  The biggest thing I'm uncertain of is the position/time dependence and why you need SMC as opposed to normal importance sampling. 

The problem of using SMC is that you can't take gradients through the partition function AFAIK.  However, you can estimate the partition function using the fact the KL divergence can recover the true distribution for the variational family, even if the posterior distribution is unnormalized.

Comment: Here is a primer on variational inference (mean-field approximation) although I assume many physicists are proficient in this area: https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.00670 .  My proposed method as I imagine it resembles this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.00308  I don't know if anyone is exploring whether there is a paper here or not.  I think there likely is and if anyone is interested in exploring, feel free to email me camfen@umich.edu .  I'm not a physicist, so writing this paper doesn't do me much good.  But it seems like a good idea and could help the physics community, so happy to help.