# Estimating partition function using Monte Carlo methods

Tags: statistical-mechanics, computational-physics, partition-function

While working on a completely unrelated quantum computing problem, I ran into a quantity that can be mapped to a partition function of spins on a triangular lattice. It is not quite an Ising model, though, since interaction happens between triplets of spins, some configurations are not allowed, and I don't explicitly have the Hamiltonian but only the weight of every configuration (I guess one could just pick a random value for the temperature and define a Hamiltonian, but it would probably just be a more complicated mess).

I have been trying to understand, if I can use Monte Carlo methods to get the partition function, but I am getting lost in the literature. From what I understood, my best shot would be to use something like the Wang-Landau algorithm to estimate the density of states and use that to get the partition function, but I couldn't find any paper detailing such a procedure so, if someone could give me some good literature to look at (or any suggestions), that would be very helpful.

Thanks!

P.S. As far as I understand, Wang-Landau gives the density of states up to a normalization constant. However, in my specific case I have some conditions on this fictitious "partition function" that should allow me to infer that constant.

Comment: Hi, you might want to look at my answer here to at least get started: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/550504/is-estimation-partition-functions-without-resorting-to-markov-chain-monte-carlo/552402#552402

Comment: What information do you have that lets you infer the normalization constant for the density of states, but doesn't let you infer the partition "function" (really just a single number, it sounds like) directly?

Comment: @Daniel I have dependence on a continuous parameter $\epsilon \in [0,1]$ and I know that the "partition function" is 1 in the limit of $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$. Since the density of states is an integer in this case, then this should allow me to get the normalization constant.

Comment: Ok! For $\epsilon$ near 0, you can use Monte Carlo to sample from the $\epsilon = 0$ distribution, and these samples will allow you to estimate the small-$\epsilon$ partition function pretty efficiently. Is an answer at small $\epsilon$ good enough for you?

Answer (score 0):

The Ising model is fairly well studied, a good start might be [this](https://www.publish.csiro.au/ph/pdf/PH740357) paper. Many numerical methods exist as well, which may be used, starting with metropolis-hastings and cluster algorithms like the Wolff/Swendsen-Wang algorithm. Frustrated systems and transverse field systems can be efficiently sampled using QMC algorithms like Determinant quantum MC (DQMC) and Stochastic Series Expansion (SSE).

Also, as far as I can remember the 2D triangular lattice is exactly solvable assuming there is no transverse field. I believe in that case you are looking for a solution using transfer matrix method.

Comment: I will look into these in the next days and let you know, thank you!